# Unity network chat, need a way around command to update chat

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm making a chat for an online game in unity. It is done with a prefab ChatObject containing a script and everything I need to draw the text and window. The chat contains a SyncListString with the last 30 messages, this is synced from server to clients but not the other way around. unity quote "that is the work of commands"

```
[Command]
void CmdUpdateChatAcross(string message)
{
    UpdateChat(message);
    RpcUpdateChat();
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcUpdateChat()
{
    UpdateChat("");
}
```

The UpdateChat() simply draw out the sync list with the new message.
This currently works fine with one server and one client as I can spawn the chat object with client authorisation. Clients need authorisation to be allowed to send commands to the server version of it. But I have not figured out (or am sure I want to) how to give authority over the chat object to ALL clients.

Do I just not do it? Find another way? There is a function to assign owner but have not figured out how it works or if it would give authority only over the local version. As I assume I cannot have multiple owners.

The server can send messages to all clients without a problem. But I cannot get players to send their messages to the server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The way I accomplished this is by giving the player prefab a script that handles passing messages to the server from the UI. This is because the player object can always send commands to the server. So, you have your UI object that takes some input from the player. It has a reference to a script on the local player that we will call NetworkPlayerBridge

```
public class NetworkPlayerBridge : NetworkBehaviour
{
    //Call this from your chat window object on the local player
    public void BroadcastChat(string msg)
    {
        CmdBroadcastChat(msg);
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdBroadcastChat(string msg)
    {
         //send this message to the chat window on the server and place
         //it in a SyncList so that all clients will be updated
    }
}
```